# nvidia-docker slow performance on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow-serving, nvidia-docker

I am using tensorflow-serving to run models on my local nvidia-docker image tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu with below configuration

- gpu:GeForce GTX 1080 with 12 GB
- Driver Version:  418.88
- CUDA Version: 10.1

But my inference is taking almost "double" time when I am running in aws-ec2 with below configuration.

- gpu: Tesla K80 with 12 GB
- Driver Version: 418.40.04
- CUDA Version: 10.1

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it happening with a specific model or is it happening to all the models?